# How can I use multiple LambdaFunctionHandler for SNSEvent and S3Event in Java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to trigger a Lambda function from s3 event and sns event.

Current version is like that:

```
public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<S3Event, Object> {

  public Object handleRequest(S3Event input, Context context) {
    context.getLogger().log("S3Event: " + input);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Is there any way to handle both event types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested on [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler-io-type-stream.html) there is low level handler.

```
public class Hello implements RequestStreamHandler{
    public static void handler(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) throws IOException {
        int letter;
        while((letter = inputStream.read()) != -1)
        {
            outputStream.write(Character.toUpperCase(letter));
        }
    }
}
```

By using these handler, I can able to convert request to S3Event and SNSEvent. There is an example code [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=EixoX/jetfuel/jetfuel-master/jetfuel-aws-lambda/src/test/java/com/eixox/api/lambda/TestUtils.java).

Answer (score 0):

As one of the approaches instead of using `S3Event` class you can simply use `Map` and decide what to do based on the view of the request object.

But more proper way would be the following. Assuming that you have common logic for S3 and SNS events, you are using some common properties from these requests. You can create your own custom base class containing this common properties, then create a common handler, which leverages this base class. See also: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-programming-model-req-resp.html

Roughly saying it can look like:

```
public class BaseCommonRequest {

     private String someCommonProperty1;

     // ...
} 

public class BaseLambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<BaseCommonRequest, Object> {

  public Object handleRequest(BaseCommonRequest input, Context context) {
    context.getLogger().log("event: " + input);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I prefer to use already existing S3Event and SNSEvent objects. These events actually are JSON and I can use JSON Parser but this make code clutter.

Comment: There is nothing bad in usage of your own types. It is a normal and expected practice. Furthermore, not all AWS events have corresponding classes in AWS Java API